# Android set items into Spinner by custom Adapter

Tags: android, android-spinner

in my application i have custom `BaseAdapter` for `Spinner` for insert data from List into that,

in this method i can return `List` as an data:

```
public List<String> getSmsNumberList() {
    return Arrays.asList(smsNumbers.split("\\s*,\\s*"));
}
```

after geting successfull data from that i'm prepare to insert into Spinner:

```
        smsNumbers = G.getInfo().getSmsNumberList();
        panel_numbers = (String[]) smsNumbers.toArray(new String[smsNumbers.size()]);
        SpinnerArrayAdapter dataAdapter = new SpinnerArrayAdapter(this);
        spinner_panel_numbers.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

`smsNumbers` have some data returned by `getSmsNumberList()` function, now i'm using this below custom BaseAdapter for view data into `Spinner` :

**Adapter code UPDATED**

```
private class SpinnerArrayAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private final LayoutInflater mInflater;
    List<String>                 list;


    public SpinnerArrayAdapter(ActivitySmsSendGroup con, List<String> list) {
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(con);
        this.list = list;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.length;
    }


    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }


    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ListContent holder;
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.panel_number_spinner_style, null);
            holder = new ListContent();

            holder.name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

            v.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ListContent) v.getTag();
        }
        holder.name.setText(list[position] + "");
        return v;
    }
}
static class ListContent {

    TextView name;
}
```

unfortunately my `Spinner` dialog dont have data and that empty

Comment: what is size of `panel_numbers` in getView method?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK i'm sorry my problem is this line, `panel_numbers = (String[]) smsNumbers.toArray(new String[smsNumbers.size()]);` size is zero

Comment: @TuzWorld: post full code of `SpinnerArrayAdapter` class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

> panel_numbers = (String[]) smsNumbers.toArray(new
>   String[smsNumbers.size()]);

Because already have List so no need to convert it to Array just add one more parameter to constructor of `SpinnerArrayAdapter` class :

```
List<String> list;
public SpinnerArrayAdapter(ActivitySmsSendGroup con,List<String> list) {
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(con);
        this.list=list;
    }
```

Now use `list` instead of `panel_numbers` everywhere in SpinnerArrayAdapter class

Pass List from Activity in `SpinnerArrayAdapter` class constructor when create object:

```
SpinnerArrayAdapter dataAdapter = new SpinnerArrayAdapter(this,smsNumbers);
```

Comment: Thanks sir. i get this problems now: First: getCount() `length cannot be resolved or is not a field` and `The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to List`  for  `setText(list[position] + "")`

Comment: @TuxWorld: use List methods for getting size and item for length use `list.size()` and for item use `list.get(position)`

Comment: unfortunately list of Spinner is empty, `smsNumbers.size()` is `1` and have some data

Comment: @TuxWorld: ok try to set static text like `holder.name.setText("Row:"+position);` are you able to see row?

Comment: i see `Row:0` in dialog

Comment: @TuxWorld: means code is working fine but `list[position]` returning empty string so you should check `getSmsNumberList` method code

Answer (score 0):

In your adapter you should add a method, and variable for your ArrayList (add your own object here)

```
public static ArrayList<ListObject> listItems;


public void addItems(ArrayList<ListObject> mListItems) {
  listItems = new ArrayList<ListObject>();
  listItems.clear();
  listItems.addAll(mListItems);
  notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Then in your main class call

```
SpinnerArrayAdapter.addItems(myList);
```

Note: Ensure within getView that your'e setting variables based on listItem in the class ie. title.setText(listItems.get(position).name);

Comment: thanks. whats `ListObject` in your code? i can not find how to import that

Comment: my sms numbers is into `smsNumbers` variable

Comment: ListObject is a custom object I added just as an example, it could be anything that you'd like your ArrayList to store (within certain parameters). For instance if you just want to have a list of Strings then it would be a ArrayList<String>

Answer (score 0):

Your adapter should look like this:

```
@Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    public View getCustomView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        View rowView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_row, parent, false);

        spnItemName = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.spnItemName);
        spnItemDel = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.spnItemDel);

        spnItemName.setText(iName.get(position)+"");

        spnItemDel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //iName[position] = null;
                iName.remove(position);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        return rowView;
    }
```

For full source code please see my [github project](https://github.com/iamsarker/android-apps/tree/master/DynamicSpinner)